# Why getting a "bus error" when playing with pointers?

Tags: c

so I was playing with pointers because I didn't know what else to do and usually, I imagine what's going on under the hood after each instruction. But I recently came against an error that I don't really understand.

```
char *str = "test";
printf("%c", ++*str);
```

Output :

```
zsh: bus error
```

Expected output was a 'u' because as far as I know, it first dereference the first address of the variable 'str' wich is a 't' than increment it right ? Or am I missing something ?

Changing the code like so is not giving me any error but why ?

```
printf("%c", *++str);
```

Thank you !

Comment: `char *str = "test";` is not correct in C++, so I assume this is C. Please only tag the language you are actually using

Comment: `++*str` attempts to increment the read-only data in the string literal.

Comment: Don't write code like this: `printf("%c", ++*str);`.  Break out your increment into a separate statement.  As @WilliamPursell explains, the dereference occurs *first,* before the increment.

Comment: Try: `char buf[] = "test"; char *str = buf; ...`

Comment: String literals are not modifiable. You could use `char str_data[] = "test"; char *str = str_data;` or `char *str = (char[]){ "test" };` instead,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot modify the data in a string literal.  What you expect will work if you do:

```
char buf[] = "test"; 
char *str = buf;
putchar(++*str);
```

because the content of `buf` is writeable.